# cannot insert datetime field with stored procedure into mysql database

Tags: mysql, pymysql, sql-timestamp, sqldatetime, mysql-date

I am getting this syntax error when trying to insert a datetime into mysql database.

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:01)' at line 1")
```

I am using pymysql and flask-mysql. This is my code:

```
  cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table_2;""")
  cursor.execute("""DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateTestProc2;""")
  testTable = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table_2 (
          time DATETIME,
          PRIMARY KEY (time)
          );
          """
  testProc = """
      CREATE PROCEDURE updateTestProc2(
        IN ptime DATETIME
      )
      BEGIN
        SET @queryStr = CONCAT('INSERT INTO test_table_2(time) VALUES ( ',
          ptime, 
          ')
          ;'
        );
        PREPARE query FROM @queryStr;
        EXECUTE query;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
      END
    """
  cursor.execute(testTable)
  cursor.execute(testProc)
  proc_input = ('1990-05-23 00:00:01',)
  cursor.callproc('updateTestProc2', proc_input)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use string concatenation to get values into statement. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameters. Change your procedure's code to:

```
...
SET @queryStr = 'INSERT INTO test_table_2 (time) VALUES (?)';
PREPARE query FROM @queryStr;
EXECUTE query USING ptime;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
...
```

`?` is a parameter placeholder that is replaced with the value of the expression you pass with `USING` when you do `EXECUTE`. That way don't need to care about escaping, quoting etc. and can't do it wrong.

Comment: hi @stickybit, I have tried inserting your code instead into the stored procedure and am getting this error
```(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ptime;\n    DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;\n  END' at line 7")
```